# ReactJS - Moment- react-moment

Tags: reactjs

I'm formatting date from mongodb in reactjs. I'm using the below code to display it in UI.

```
<td> <Moment format="DD-MMM-YYYY">{ this.props.item.date }</Moment></td>
```

If the date is not available then it's printing the current date. How to print null if the date is not present in mongodb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use expressions to handle that e.g.

```
<td> 
   <Moment format="DD-MMM-YYYY"> 
   { this.props.item.date ? this.props.item.date : null }
   </Moment>
</td>
```

If you meant to display nothing then put the expression above the element something like this

```
 <td>
   { this.props.item.date ?
   <Moment format="DD-MMM-YYYY">
    {this.props.item.date}
   </Moment> : null
   }
 </td>
```

Comment: Thanks., it showing "Invalid Date" instead of null or " "

Comment: Am not able to parse the date from mongodb and render in textbox.

<input name="date" type="date" disabled={ this.state.mode } value={ this.state.item.date ? <Moment format="DD-MMM-YYYY">{ this.state.item.date }</Moment> : null } className="form-control" onChange={ this.handleInputChange } />

Am trying with the above code. Please suggest..

Comment: @Karthikeyan Open a new question please.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

`<td> <Moment format="DD-MMM-YYYY">{ this.props.item.date ? this.props.item.date : 'null'  }</Moment></td>`

You can use a ternary expression to conditionally render components.